# How to integrate Django Rest APIs with BackboneJS frontend for single page application

Tags: django, backbone.js, django-rest-framework, single-page-application

I am not able to comprehend what would be pros and cons of the following approaches in making a single page backbone application using RESTful APIs from Django Rest Framework.

1. Render the whole app from within Django's template.
2. Serve the backbone app from another server ie node server. With nginx in the front for both servers.
3. Serve the HTML/Templates and JS from a separate CDN.

What are the things to take care ie points of caution in each strategy. Is there any other way to tie them up which I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question, and really it has nothing to do with Django or Backbone.  What you're really asking about is a "thick-client" architecture vs. a "thin-client" architecture.  In other words, having your user interface rendered on the client vs. having it rendered on the server.

First, allow me to recap a few things to make sure we're on the same page.  The "thin-client" approach is the traditional/old school model, and the model Django itself is based on.  The server renders HTML, sends it to the client, and whenever the client wants to do something it sends data back to the server and asks for fresh HTML.

In contrast the more modern "thick-client" approach lets the client render all of the UI.  Whenever the client needs to do something it makes an AJAX request to a (presumably REST-ful) API, powered by a library like Django REST Framework.  That API just returns the relevant data, and leaves it up to the client to render it appropriately.

There are advantages and disadvantages to both approaches, but the thick-client approach is becoming more and more popular because:

1. network transactions are faster: because your server is only sending the exact JSON you need instead of a mess of HTML, the "payload" of the response is much smaller
2. you can fetch all data "behind the scenes"; this makes things appear faster to the user, and lets you implement UI paradigms (eg. infinite scroll) that a thin client can't
3. the client/server relationship is simpler, because the people writing server code never have to even think about HTML or any other presentation logic; they get to just focus on the data (which, being server engineers, is probably the part they're most interested in anyway)

This is why a lot of companies (including the one I work for) have all but abandoned Django proper in favor of API endpoints served by Django REST Framework.

So, if you want to go with a thick client architecture, Django should never serve anything except the very first HTML page (and even that could be served by ngnix if you wanted, since it's just static HTML).  After that you'd use a `Backbone.Router` and `Backbone.Views` to render your site.  Whenever you need new information from the server you'd `fetch` a `Backbone.Model` or `Backbone.Collection` (with its `url` property pointing to your Django REST Framework endpoint).

I can attest that this whole approach works great; the site I work on is very complex, with many endpoints, and Backbone + Django REST Framework handles it beautifully.  The only (slightly) tricky part is caching: in the thin client approach the browser automatically caches pages for you, but since there are no "pages" in a thick client (just AJAX responses with data) there is no automatic caching.  This means that if you want to cache data you'll need to do it yourself, for instance with a `Backbone.Collection` devoted to that purpose.

Hope that helps.

P.S. Back in the day Django REST Framework didn't handle Django authentication stuff (ie. logging in/out) quite the way we wanted, so we wound up serving one other page, our login page, from Django.  However I'm pretty sure the current Django REST Framework handles authentication stuff much better now, so this likely won't be an issue for you.

Comment: Thats a very thorough answer. There are few more motifs which would be interesting to learn from your experience.  1. Do you keep models in django and backbone in sync ie one on one mapping? For complex apps, I feel this mapping breaks away to a more complex structure. What are the design patterns / tactics to handle this you see have worked for you. 2. What are the security implications of thick client?

Comment: 1: Yes and no.  Some `Models` are simple and just use the server representation directly (eg. our User `Model` just wraps the JSON of a Django user).  Other data can be more complex, and for those we often have very simple Models for the parts, and then the `Models` we actually use (ie. the ones with all the logic) are composed of those smaller `Models` (eg. we have a "Meeting" `Model` that is actually the combination of multiple database rows; while we have a `Collection` to fetch those rows, the `Model` merges them in to something we can actually work with).

Comment: 2: That's an interesting topic.  The short answer is that nothing on the client (thick or thin) can ever be secure; the end user's browser (and thus any attacker) has to be able to read it.  You can obfuscate your JS, but that only slows down an attacker: it doesn't stop them (they don't even need your JS really, all they need is the "Net" tab of their developer tool).  With that said, thick clients and their (nice, clean, easy to understand) REST-ful APIs are probably easier for an attacker ... but in both cases it's just a matter of time.  The real place for security concern is the server.

Comment: On 1. thats an interesting approach. Is there any blog or some literature on this strategy?

Comment: Sorry, there may well be but I don't happen to know of any good ones off-hand.  Really it's just a more specific application of Object Composition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).